# Customize the default keyword behaviour when used over a custom type?

Tags: c#, default

In C# the [`default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword can be used to get the default value of a given type:

```
enum E1 { A,B,C,D }
enum E2 { A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4 }

int i = default(int);         // i = 0
MyClass c = default(MyClass); // c = null
E1 e1 = default(E1);          // e1 = A;
E2 e2 = default(E2);          // e2 = 0;
```

But sometimes, getting a `null` as a default value for a class is not convenient (and also some coders have the opinion that returning `null` is not the best choice).

Suppose that I want to return a well-known and controlled instance of `MyClass` as the result of the expression `default(MyClass)`, for example:

```
class MyClass
{
    // Default value.
    private static MyClass default_value = new MyClass();
    // Default 'converter'.
    public MyClass() {  }

    // Default 'converter'... I've tried: it doesn't work.
    public MyClass default { return default_value; }
}

MyClass c = default(MyClass); // c = MyClass.default_value
```

AfaIk there's no way to customize the way the `default` keyword works to achieve the behaviour I want but anyways I'm not a C# expert so the question is:

- Is there any C# construct or workarround to customize the `default` keyword behaviour when used over a custom type?

Comment: It would probably be better (for you and anyone using your code down the road) to simply add a static method to return what you consider a 'default' instance e.g. `MyClass defInstance = MyClass.Default;` Once you start down the rabbit hole of trying to redefine expected behavior from built-in keywords, you'll only create a headache for everyone involved.

Comment: @Nate222 but with a static method or property we cannot use the value in generics code. `void f<T>() { T t = default(T); /* play with t... */ print(t.ToString()); }`

Comment: You're right about default and generics. But - you're also out of luck.